Good quality tact switches for mouse?
I have a Logitech T400 mouse:

which I love. It is getting old and the tact switches

are failing. Normally you would just buy a new mouse, however this kind of mouse is not manufactured anymore and I would like to keep it as it is really a nice one. I have replaced the tact switches already about 2 years ago, and I am now looking for top notch quality tact switches which can last for ~5 years, which is normal in brand new mouses. Which is the best manufacturer of tact switches for this application?

Haven't kept up with the mouse switch space too much, but Kalih, TTC, and Omron are all popular.
